# About the number of independent forecasts in the Fundamental Law of Active Management

Tags: portfolio-management, ratio, information

The original FLAM predicts the information ratio by

$$ 
IR = IC \times \sqrt{N}
$$ 
where $IR$ is the Information Ratio, $IC$ is the information Coefficient and $N$ is **the number of independent forecasts**. Later this law is improved several times, but the term $ IC \times \sqrt{N}$ is always present. I don't seem to understand (and find a good practical example) of what is exactly $N$ and how to calculate it.

I would be grateful if someone explains the exact definition of $N$. What is an independent forecast? It may seem a stupid question to some, but for me it is fundamental.

In Zhou and Jain, Active Equity Management, it is written:

> $N$ is the number of independent bets in a year, it has two aspects: the number of cross-sectional bets on different assets at any point in time and the number of independent bets on the same asset across time.

In this context what exactly is **cross-sectional bet** and **independent bet on the same asset**? It would be best if someone gives a small portfolio example.

Answer (score 1):

There is no such thing as number of independent bets when one is betting on a common random factor as we quants usually do. Grinold & Kahn’s formula is only relevant when the factor payoff is a constant over time. This is not interesting in practice. When the factor payoff is random, then Ding and Martin [The Fundamental Law of Active Management: Redux](https://papers.ssrn.com/sol3/papers.cfm?abstract_id=2730434) (2017) showed that the portfolio IR is basically IC divided by IC standard deviations.

To put it more bluntly , the G&K formula is useless and misleading. It is a joke that CFAers have to learn this stuff.

Answer (score 0):

See the paper by Ding and Martin (2017), "The fundamental law of active management, Redux", published in the Journal of Empirical Finance.

Comment: Could you add some detail to make this answer self-contained?

Comment: please see here for more discussion on the same question: https://quant.stackexchange.com/questions/73655/confusion-about-the-proof-of-fundamental-law-of-active-management-in-grinold-k/73768#73768

Answer (score 0):

You can think of it as the number of trading positions on `Uncorrelated` instruments, in a year.

So backtest your strategy in some uncorrelated instruments for a year, and sum their positions count.