# Confusion about the proof of Fundamental Law of Active Management in Grinold & Kahn (2000)

Tags: portfolio-management, information, active-investing

I'm reading Grinold & Kahn (2000) for the proof of the Fundamental Law of Active Management.

I can't understand formula (6A.20) on page 168, which says:

> Finally, by assuming that all the signals have equal value,
> $$\zeta_b^2=\rho^2=IC^2  \qquad \text{(6A.20)}$$

According to (6A.18) at the end of page 167, $\zeta_b^2$ is sum of square of correlation coefficients:
$$\zeta_b^2=\sum_{n=1}^{N}\rho_{n,b}^2  \qquad \text{(6A.18)}$$

where $\rho_{n,b}=corr(x_n,y_b)$. (I can't provide the whole proof here. You may read the book for more detail about $x_n$ and $y_n$.)

How can this sum of square of correlation coefficients be equal to $IC^2$(square of information coefficient)?

I think the $IC$ should be $corr(\theta_n,z_b)$ or $corr(x_n, y_b)$(I'm not sure about this, because the author doesn't give a clear formula for $IC$). But (6A.20) can't be derived from either of these two possibilities. Could anyone give some explanations about formula (6A.20)?

Answer (score -1):

Please read the paper by Ding and Martin (2017), "The fundamental law of active management: Redux". The paper is available here:
https://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/S0927539817300543

After you read the paper, you will realize that the Grinold and Kahn fundamental law is basically flawed. The real fundamental law is just

IR=IC_mean/IC_stdev

There is no such thing as breadth, period.

Comment: I have read Ding and Martin (2017), in which the authors provide their own version of FLAM.  Though the concept 'breadth' in Grinold & Kahn (2000) is ambiguous, I still want to understand the proof in  Grinold & Kahn (2000) from a mathematical point of view. Note my question is about the IC part, not the Breadth part.

Comment: It will be a miracle if anybody can understand G&K's proof. The step in (6A.18) may not be defined at all, just like their many other formulas. Basically G&K's result is not valid and is based on some very confusing assumptions. At first you thought they are talking about a single factor model, but it looks like a k- (or BR-) factor model in their derivation. Their result does not hold even if it is based on multi-factor model just as you figured out.

Comment: Under their assumptions, for a single factor model, the result should be IR=IC*sqrt(N) where N is the number of stocks in the universe. For a multi-factor model, the result should be IR=sqrt((IC(1)^2+IC(2)^2+...+IC(k)^2)*N)=IC*sqrt(N*k) when all the ICs are the same. This is not an interesting case at all since the most important risk in factor investing is the uncertainty of factor returns. They assume that factor returns are constants which is not true in practice and if it is true then they have a money machine.

Comment: By the way, I have another question about Ding and Martin (2017). In this paper, $\Sigma_t$, defined by equation 8,  is covariance matrix of residual returns, which is equivalent to $VR$ in G&K's notation. However, the rank of  covariance matrix of residual returns is $N-1$, and it is a singular matrix. So I wonder why Ding and Martin (2017) uses the inverse of $\Sigma_t$ directly, not considering whether it is invertible or not. This usage of inverse of residual covariance matrix can also be found in Clarke, Silva   and Thorley (2006), Buckle(2004) etc.

Comment: You made a very good observation. Financial models are not like pure mathematical models. They are just approximation of the real world observations. Ding and Martin (2017) model is not perfect but it is a much closer approximation to the real world practice than those of G&K, Clarke, de Silva and Thorley (2002,2006). Your question can lead to the dispute if CAPM itself is a good description of the world. What is the market portfolio, is it S&P 500, or Russell 3000, or Whilshire 5000, or should it include all the risky assets in the world, such as gold, silver, crypto etc?

Comment: Even if we know the "market" portfolio, then what is the real "beta". Every beta people use is estimated in certain ways. Is beta a constant? is it time varying as in Bali, Engle and Tang (2016)? So strictly speaking the residual return covariance matrix (if we know the "true" model) should be rank N-1 but then no theoretical portfolio can be constructed because Sima_t is non-invertable. This is also true in G&K (p164). It claims "Note that A has rank N-1" but then the next paragraph starts with "If the residual returns are uncorrelated" which is self-contradictory.

Comment: In real world practice, some broad market proxy index, such as S&P 500, Russell 3000, etc, is used to represent the market portfolio, and some regression approach is used to estimate the "beta". So the assumption that Sigma_t is non-singular may not be so unresonable for practical purposes. In any case, there may not be a "true" model in real world, just some models are more useful than the others.

Comment: I want to add one more point here. The linear dependency of the residual returns  from the CAPM model which leads to Sigma_t rank deficiency is non-essential to Ding & Martin's fundamental law. This is also true even for G&K, Clarke, de Silva and Thorley. Theoretically, after adjusting for CAPM and get the residual returns, we can simply drop one asset from the universe and keep the remaining N-1 assets. We can then model the N-1 assets as in Ding and Martin (2017) and get all the theoretical results with N replaced by N-1. The result is almost the same when N is large.

Comment: Thanks for your explanation.  It's enlightening to drop one asset from the universe, making the covariance matrix invertible. I have another question about the detail in Ding and Martin (2017).  After the equation (10), the authors said "our use of conditional forecast error variance is a major difference between the risk model used in this paper and the risk models used in ...  Grinold and Kahn (2000)...". But I can't see any difference between formula (8) in Ding and Martin(2017) and formula (6A.5) in GK2000, both of which are conditional covariance matrix of residual returns.

Comment: Equation (8) in Ding and Martin (2017) is just a general definition of conditional covariance. It is defined for any possible model. The actual form is model dependent and is defined in equation (29) for their single factor model and in equation (38) for their multi-factor model. In both formulas the z is in the covariance matrix as an known element since it is conditional on z. They then derive the fundamental law based on their model assumptions.

Comment: However, it is almost impossible to understand the G&K math according to their setup. On the one hand, Equation (6A.4) states:  E(theta|z)=alpha(z)=A*P*J*z=B*z (here I denote A*P*J=B) where B is Nxk and z is kx1. one would think B is the factor exposures and z is the factor returns. But then in their foot note on p165, they say E(theta(n))=b*z(n), now it seems b is factor return and z(n) is factor exposure for each stock n. That is why you won't be able to understand their derivation because they never clearly defined a model.

Comment: In G&K's (6A.4) since B=A*P*J is Nxk, the remaining z is more like a kx1 factor return vector. To write E(theta|z)=B*z can only mean two things: 1) E(theta|z(t))=B*z(t) (I added a t here to indicate the factor return dynamics) means we know the factor return z(t) beforehand. This is totally not true in reality since nobody knows at time t-1 what the factor return will be for time t.  or 2) E(theta|z(t))=B*z(t)_pred where z(t)_pred is a prediction for z(t) and usually it is just a historical mean. In this situation there will be a factor return prediction error covariance needs to be included.

Comment: (6A.4) in GK2000 is linear predictor of $\boldsymbol{\theta}$. You can get this formula from pure mathematical view: the perpendicular projection of $\theta_n$ on the linear space spanned by $\boldsymbol{z}$. Or you can view (6A.4) as a linear regression of $\theta_n$ on a set of z_scores in $\boldsymbol{z}$. My question is about (6A.5). It is also **a conditional covariance matrix given information $\boldsymbol{z}$**, which is the same as the multi-factor version formula of equation (38) in Ding & Marin (2017), though they have different formula because of the difference in assumptions.

Comment: Since Ding & Martin (2017) and GK2000 both use **conditional covariance matrix** as the risk model, why Ding and Martin (2017) said "our use of conditional forecast error variance is a major difference between the risk model used in this paper and the risk models used in ... Grinold and Kahn (2000)..."

Comment: I am not sure if you have worked on a security level cross-sectional factor model in practice before. The difficulty in answering your questions regarding (6A.5) lies on the fact that the factor model is not clearly defined in G&K. According to (6A.1) θ should be an Nx1 security level excess return vector. Since B=A*P*J is Nxk, so z must be kx1. Thus z is not security level factor exposure z-scores, it is a factor returns vector. So (6A.4) can only be the perpendicular projection of θ on the linear space spanned by B, not z.

Comment: Thus G&K is assuming a factor model with fixed factor exposures B and known factor return z. Both are not true in practice. In practice, factor exposures B (such as P/E or Momentum) are time varying, and factor return z is not known beforehand. Thus both equations (6A.4) and (6A.5) are invalid and the result is then not meaningful. If, as in G&K’s footnote on p165 and as you mentioned above, z is a set of z-scores, then z must be Nxk if there are k factors. In this case both (6A.4) and (6A.5) will take different forms and will be close to what Ding and Martin (2017) presented.

Comment: I think you have confused the distinction between population and sample. In practice, if we have 2 factors, say P/E and Momentum, for 10 stocks, we usually use each stock's own P/E and Momentum to predict its own return. However, from the population point of view, we actually have 2x10=20 signals, $\boldsymbol{z}=[P/E_1, Momentum_1, P/E_2, Momentum_2,\cdots P/E_{10}, Momentum_{10}]$. Each element in $\boldsymbol{z}$ is a random variable. We use all of these 20 signals to predict the return for every stock, though not every element in $\boldsymbol{z}$ is relevant for every stock.

Comment: So, if we have 2 factors, say P/E and Momentum, for 10 stocks, $\boldsymbol{z}$ is a 20x1 vector of random signals, not 10x2 matrix of realized sample value of those random signals. This is the correct understanding of (6A.4). Please read 'REFINING FORECASTS: MULTIPLE ASSETS AND MULTIPLE FORECASTS' section on page 271 of GK2000. With two forecasts g and g' on each of 500 stocks, the signal vector $\boldsymbol{z}$ is 1000x1. That's why the author said the covariance matrix of g and g' is 1000 by 1000, and the covariance of the returns and g and g' is a 500 by 1000 matrix.

Comment: English is not my native language, so I don't know whether I have explained it clearly. I think the proof in GK2000 is almost right, but they didn't explain (6A.20) clearly. After a few days of study, now I think the proof should be: $IR^2\approx \sum_{n=1}^N\sum_{b=1}^{BR}\rho_{n,b}^2$. This is (6A.17). Then, we don't need to change the order of summation to get (6A.18).

Comment: Instead, we have $IC_n^2=\sum_{b=1}^{BR}IC_{x_n,y_b}^2=\sum_{b=1}^{BR}[corr(x_n,y_b)]^2=\sum_{b=1}^{BR}\rho_{n,b}^2$, because we use BR uncorrelated signals $\boldsymbol{y}$ to predict each $x_n$ in $\boldsymbol{x}$.  This is the combined IC of using BR uncorrelated signals to predict $x_n$ (see equation 10.27 on page 210, equation 10A.23 on page 292, and equation 6.9 on page 159). Then, we have $IR^2=\sum_{n=1}^N\sum_{b=1}^{BR}\rho_{n,b}^2=\sum_{n=1}^N\left(\sum_{b=1}^{BR}\rho_{n,b}^2\right)=\sum_{n=1}^NIC_n^2$.

Comment: Finally, if we assume each predicting model have same combined IC, we have $IR^2=N\cdot IC^2$. So, the proof in GK2000 is almost correct, with a little adjustment in the end of their proof.

Comment: Now, you can see that the breadth is $N$, 'the number of independent forecasts of exceptional return' (page 148), not $BR$, the number of signals. The use of $BR$ by GK is indeed misleading.

Comment: Now you may ask why the number of independent forecasts is $N$. That's because we use $BR$ signals $\boldsymbol{y}$ to predict $\boldsymbol{x}$ and the elements in $\boldsymbol{x}$ are uncorrelated. Actually, in GK's proof, we have the original residual return vector $\boldsymbol{\theta}$ and the uncorrelated return vector $\boldsymbol{x}$. We also have the original signal vector $\boldsymbol{z}$ and the uncorrelated signal vector $\boldsymbol{y}$. The correlation among signals have influence on the combined IC, and the correlation among residual returns have influence on the breadth.

Comment: If we use uncorrelated signals $\boldsymbol{y}$ to predict uncorrelated returns $\boldsymbol{x}$, the squared combined IC is the sum of square IC for each signal, and the breadth is $N$, the number of elements of $\boldsymbol{x}$. However, if we use the original signal vector $\boldsymbol{z}$ to predict uncorrelated returns $\boldsymbol{x}$, the combined IC should consider the correlation between signals (equation 10A.23), but the breadth is still the number of elements of $\boldsymbol{x}$. If we use  $\boldsymbol{y}$ to predict the original residual return $\boldsymbol{\theta}$, then ....

Comment: ... then the squared combined IC is the sum of squared IC for each signal, but the breadth is not $N$, because the correlations between residual returns in $\boldsymbol{\theta}$ make the forecasts of each $\theta_n$ not independent. So, you can see why GK 'introduce orthogonal bases $\boldsymbol{x}$ and $\boldsymbol{y}$ for both the residual returns $\boldsymbol{\theta}$ and the information signals $\boldsymbol{z}$' (page 164). These orthogonal bases can make the calculation of combined IC and breadth simple to get the FLAM: $IR^2=N\cdot IC^2$.

Comment: As I said in my last comment, it is very difficult to make a meaningful argument if we do not specify what kind of model relates the returns and the signals. In your 2-factor example, you are saying that the z’s are factor exposures and should be 2Nx1 instead of Nx2. But then how can we relate this to (6A.4) since A*P*J is NxN and z is 2Nx1? What kind of forecasting model we are talking about? How do we get those A, P and J in practice since the only information we have are historical stock returns and factor exposures (by your assumption, it is z)?

Comment: $\boldsymbol{APJ}$ is NxBR, i.e. the number of stocks times the number of signals, not NxN. $\boldsymbol{z}$ is BRx1. In my example, BR=2xN. What kind of forecasting model we are talking about? It's linear predictor of $\boldsymbol{\theta}$ given $\boldsymbol{z}$, including multifactor model as a special case. A, P and J have clear definition. In practice, you don't need to actually calculate A, P or J. We just use these entities to prove FLAM. In case you indeed want to get A, P or J, you can use historical data to estimate it.

Comment: I think anyone who have a solid mathematical background can understand the proof in GK2000. Just as many of the articles about FLAM after GK2000 point out, the problem of GK's FLAM is that the breadth is ambiguous when the residual returns are correlated with each other. No one says that the proof of GK is problematic.

Comment: Sorry my mistake. APJ is NxBR. Now assume your understanding of G&K is correct, then BR=Nxk where k is the number of factors. With 1000 stocks and 10 factors (both are very common in quant investing, at least in the US) we have BR=10000. So A will be 1000x1000, P will be 1000x10000, and J will be 10000x10000. The unique number of parameters in A is 1000x1001/2, in P will be 1000x10000, and in J will be 10000x10001/2, a total of 60,505,500 parameters. Let's also assume we have 20 years of monthly data, then the total number of data observations we have is 1000x11x240=2,640,000

Comment: So I am wondering how can anybody estimate 60,505,500 parameters with just 2,640,000 observations. Nobody will have a clue unless it's god-given. Now with your interpretation, assume the IC=0.05 which is very common (I remembered G&K mentioned this somewhere, and their numerical example given on p266 assumed IC=0.0833), with BR=10000, we would expect a portfolio with IR=IC*sqrt(BR)=5. This is even not annualized if the model is in monthly horizon. It will be laughable if somebody claims that he/she has a strategy with IR=5. As a reference, Buffett's BRK-A has a IR of 0.11, annualized 0.38.

Comment: The estimation of A, P or J is irrelevant for the proof of FLAM. It's another question and a question of practice. Just as the estimation of $\boldsymbol{V}$, sample variance is a bad estimator and we can use a structural risk model instead (chapter 3). Similarly, sample (co)variance is not a good estimator for A, P or J. But you may use other methods to estimate them. Note I said you could use 'historical data' to estimate A, P or J. But that's not to say that you use sample variance as estimator. The structural risk model for $\boldsymbol{V}$ is also based on 'historical data'.

Comment: As to your example for the IR, I have three points to say. First, breadth is ** not the number of signals**. It's the number of independent forecasts, and if all the residual returns of your 1000 stocks are uncorrelated, the number of independent forecasts if 1000, not 10000. I hope you read my explanation in above comments seriously then we can have a good discussion. Second, if breadth=1000, then IR=1.58. You may say this large IR is also rare in practice. That's because the breadth is impossible to be 1000 in practice if you have 1000 stocks....

Comment: The key is the "structure" when you say structural risk model and that is the key point of Ding and Martin (2017). The risk in investing is related to forecasting error of the residual returns which is only defined when you clearly specify your forecasting model. If you can predict stock returns perfectly then there is no risk for you in investing. In any case, I should congratulate you if you have fully understood the G&K math and hopefully you can also apply them into investment practice in the future. It's a nice discussion. Thank you!

Comment: There must be correlations between those 1000 stocks' residual return. Thus the number of independent forecasts (i.e. breadth) is less than 1000 **in practice**. Third, be that as it may, the GK's FLAM has its own problem. The IR in GK's FLAM is unbounded. Ding & Martin (2017) has some discussion about this point.

Comment: BTW, just saw this latest paper by Ding and his coauthor, thought you might be interested. https://link.springer.com/article/10.1057/s41260-022-00295-9